# Android error, Method getText must be called from UI thread, currently infered thread is worker. what to do?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am getting this error.Android error, Method getText must be called from UI thread, currently, infered thread is worker. what to do? I have tried almost all the solutions I found out but still it is not working. Anybody can help? Trying to solve it but nothing helps. what do I do now? Thanks in advance

```
package net.simple.insertintomysql;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     EditText editTextStoreName;
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextFeedback;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextStoreName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextstoreName);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextFeedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFeedback);

    }

    public void insert(View view){
        String storename = editTextStoreName.getText().toString();
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String feedback= editTextFeedback.getText().toString();
        insertToDatabase(storename,name,feedback);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String storename, String name, String feedback){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               final String paramStorename = params[0];
                String paramName = params[1];
                String paramFeedback = params[2];

                //InputStream is = null;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      final  String storename = editTextStoreName.getText().toString();
                      final  String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                        final  String feedback = editTextFeedback.getText().toString();
                    }
                });


                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storename", storename));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedback", feedback));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://10.238.4.249/new/user_feedback.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    //is = entity.getContent();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(storename, name, feedback);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: see what methods of `AsyncTask` are run in the UI thread

Comment: Yes its true. You have already define your method like `private void insertToDatabase(String storename, String name, String feedback){..` Then why are you using  `String storename = editTextStoreName.getText().toString();
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String feedback = editTextFeedback.getText().toString();`. Just use `private void insertToDatabase(editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextFeedback.getText().toString()){`

Comment: Android doesn't allow to access Ui components from background threads. However, if you read the `AsyncTask` docs you'll see that it has 3 specific methods to work with the Ui Thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: doInBackground runs in background thread. You should not access any UI elements over here..

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code may be it help you out:

```
 private void insertToDatabase(Activity activity){
            class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String storename=null;
 String name=null;
String feedback=null;
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String paramStorename = params[0];
                    String paramName = params[1];
                    String paramFeedback = params[2];

                    //InputStream is = null;
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                storename = editTextStoreName.getText().toString();
                     name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                   feedback = editTextFeedback.getText().toString();
          }
      });


                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storename", storename));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedback", feedback));

                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                                "http://10.238.4.249/new/user_feedback.php");
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                        //is = entity.getContent();


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    return "success";
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                    textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
                }
            }
            SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
            sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(storename, name, feedback);
        }
```

let me know your response.

Comment: What exactly is `activity` here? In case that is somehow a `Context` then this solution is wrong because the context might not be available when the task is executed.

Comment: didn't work. Showing error as " variable accessed within from inner class, use final ". for these lines " nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storename", storename));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedback", feedback));"  i tried using final keyword. but didnt help

Comment: @user7939485 make the variables global.let me edit the answer

Comment: @DeepakRana: It worked but data is not storing into DB. Do you know why?